# How to display Google Game Services popups in libGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have been trying to add the `setPopUpView()` in my LibGDX project but it's not displaying. Here is my code.

```
 private void signInSilently() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                            GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(AndroidLauncher.this, signedInAccount);
                            View view = new View(AndroidLauncher.this);
                            gamesClient.setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP);
                            gamesClient.setViewForPopups(view);
                            onConnected(task.getResult());
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInSilently(): success");
                        } else {
                            onDisconnected();
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInSilently(): failure", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve a `View` from `AndroidLauncher` activity:

```
GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(AndroidLauncher.this, signedInAccount);
gamesClient.setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
gamesClient.setViewForPopups(((AndroidGraphics) AndroidLauncher.this.getGraphics()).getView());
// or, which is the same thing
// gamesClient.setViewForPopups(((AndroidGraphics) Gdx.graphics).getView());
```

And you probably would want to put these three lines of code in `onConnected()` method.